# How may I scroll with vim into a big file?

Tags: vim, large-files

I have a big file with thousands of lines of thousands of characters.

I move the cursor to 3000th character.

If I use <kbd>PageDown</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, the file will scroll but the cursor will come back to the first no-space character.

There's is an option to set to keep the cursor in the same column after a such scroll ?

I have the behavior with gvim on *Window*, vim on *OpenVMS* and *Cygwin*.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
CTRL-E - scroll down
CTRL-Y - scroll up
```

100`<CTRL-E>` will scroll down 100 lines for example

If you like using <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, <kbd>PageDown</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> etc. you can set the "nostartofline" option

```
:set nostartofline
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, one easy way to do so is using the movement keys. For example, to go down 100 lines keeping the cursor at the same column: "100j"

Edit:

Alright, searching a little more to really find an answer to your question, there's an option to do exactly what you want:

```
:set nostartofline
```

Comment: You posted your answer 1-2 minutes after Phil. I had to choose. I choose the fastest.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

### A Recent Plugin

I am using [terryma/vim-smooth-scrolling](https://github.com/terryma/vim-smooth-scroll) plugin as it provides a very nice and smooth scrolling.

---

To **install**, you can use [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle):

```
Bundle terryma/vim-smooth-scrolling
```

As stated in the doc, you can set up 3 arguments: **distance**, **duration** and **speed**.

I am using this in my **.vimrc** file:

```
noremap <silent> <c-b> :call smooth_scroll#up(&scroll*2, 10, 4)<CR>
noremap <silent> <c-f> :call smooth_scroll#down(&scroll*2, 10, 4)<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not suit your situation at all, but if it makes it easier to break the lines up you can break them at a certain character e.g. after  ':'

```
:%s/:/\r&/g
```

Or every 80 characters

```
:%s/.\{80}/&\r/g
```