# How do I scroll through a terminal using Vim 8.1's new terminal/termpack support?

Tags: vim

I love the new terminal support that Vim 8.1 offers and I like that up/down are mapped to the terminal, so that you can select prior commands. How can I scroll up and down the terminal however? Currently, in my GDB program output window I see characters like this:

^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[D^[[D^[[

And in the terminal window it just moves between prior commands.

Comment: "(TODO: scrolling when the terminal is larger than the window)"

Comment: @sergio `k` and `j` don't scroll in the terminal. they type the k and j characters.

Answer (score 162):

You have to switch to '*Terminal-Normal mode*' with <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd> (that's **Ctrl-w**, *capital **N***). Then you can use the usual Vim commands to move around, cut, copy and paste.

Once finished, press either <kbd>**i**</kbd> or <kbd>**a**</kbd> to resume using the terminal as before.

Comment: To enter de normal mode (vim 8.1), this is the combination that worked for me: `Ctrl-\ Ctrl-n`.

Comment: Getting back to the terminal is done by entering INSERT MODE, puzzled me for a bit :)

Comment: For clarity :-)

press `i` or `a` to go back to normal terminal mode

Answer (score 12):

I do this:

```
tnoremap <c-b> <c-\><c-n>
```

And then `<C-b>` whenever I need to scroll back up, using gg to go all the way up, then G to come back down, (or `<C-F>` for page by page). I press 'i' or 'a' from any page to enter commands in the shell. Simplicity itself.

Comment: wow I didn't know about tnoremap, this works great...thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `neovim`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> to enter normal mode in a terminal.

The help (`:help terminal-input`) says the following:

> In this mode all keys except `<C-\><C-N>` are sent to the underlying program. Use `<C-\><C-N>` to return to normal-mode. `CTRL-\_CTRL-N`

Also, if you do this often, I recommend mapping it to something more convenient, like a double tap of Escape:

```
tnoremap <Esc><Esc> <C-\><C-n>
```

(That way you can still use programs in the command line, that require escape to retain it's original functionality, since if you don't press anything else, it will just send a regular escape event after your defined [timeout](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27timeout%27) [length](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27timeoutlen%27).)